# JQuery find a button in td class

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have following source code:

```
<table class="xrounded_shadowed" id="cancel_leave">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="column_c_leave_ref_no">LEAVE REF. NO</th>
<th class="column_EMPLOYEE">EMPLOYEE</th>
<th class="column_APPROVAL STATUS">APPROVAL STATUS</th>
<th class="row_action"></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td class="column_c_leave_ref_no" style="">00148</td>
<td class="column_EMPLOYEE" style="">Cat Grant (cat)</td>
<td class="column_APPROVAL STATUS" style="">Pending Approval</td>
<td class="row_action"> <a href="abc">Cancel</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td class="column_c_leave_ref_no" style="">00145</td>
<td class="column_EMPLOYEE" style="">Cat Grant (cat)</td>
***<td class="column_APPROVAL STATUS" style="">Approved</td>***
<td class="row_action"> ***<a href="abc">Cancel</a>***
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I use JQuery to select the button when "`column_APPROVAL STATUS == Approved`" ? Because I want to change that button's `href` from `abc` to another link, e.g. `xyz`

Comment: `:contains('text string')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how to select the ```Cancel href``` in ```$("td:contains('Approved')")``` ? I need to change the ```href```` from abc to xyz. Thank you.

Comment: That link is not a child of that td.  It is the `next()` sibling td's child

Comment: the link is in ```<td class="row_action">```. Do you know how to show the a href value (abc) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#cancel_leave tbody .column_APPROVAL.STATUS:contains("Approved")').next('.row_action').find('a').prop('href', 'xyz');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="xrounded_shadowed" id="cancel_leave">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column_c_leave_ref_no">LEAVE REF. NO</th>
      <th class="column_EMPLOYEE">EMPLOYEE</th>
      <th class="column_APPROVAL STATUS">APPROVAL STATUS</th>
      <th class="row_action"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="column_c_leave_ref_no" style="">00148</td>
      <td class="column_EMPLOYEE" style="">Cat Grant (cat)</td>
      <td class="column_APPROVAL STATUS" style="">Pending Approval</td>
      <td class="row_action"> <a href="abc">Cancel</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="column_c_leave_ref_no" style="">00145</td>
      <td class="column_EMPLOYEE" style="">Cat Grant (cat)</td>
      <td class="column_APPROVAL STATUS" style="">Approved</td>
      <td class="row_action"> <a href="abc">Cancel</a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use the `:contains` selector on the td containing the `Approved` text, then use `next()` to get the td after it, find the nested link in that td, and then change its href.